# facebook sharer extra parameters, define where to share

Tags: facebook, share

I want to use the sharer.php popup to open the share dialog, but would like to customize it so that the share option is by default not to my profile, but to a page - and ideally also select the page (by id?).

i've looked everywhere but the only documented parameters are ?url= and ?title=, although it seems that there is less known "hidden" way to also define summary and image: ?p[image]= ...

im hoping there is something similar to define the share options?

or perhaps another share screen that i can use to post directly to my page?

tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid usage of Sharer in favor of Feed Dialog.

Feed Dialog may be used to specify where the content is published (`to`) and who publishing it user or page (`from`).

You can use Feed Dialog directly or with JaveScript SDK, [read the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) for more details.